# Converting raw sql to sql alchemy ORM

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I'm looking to convert the following sql statement to sql alchemy

```
select c1.id, c1.repository, c1.branch, c1.failed_step, c1.stop_time
from completed_builds as c1
where c1.stop_time = (
    select max(c2.stop_time)
    from completed_builds as c2
    where c1.branch = c2.branch
    and c1.repository = c2.repository
)
and c1.repository in ('flex', 'mob', 'tv')
and c1.branch in ('stage', 'int')
order by c1.repository, c1.branch
```

This outputs unique branch + repository pairs with the highest stop_time value.

Thank you very much!

Comment: ```select distinct completed_builds.*
from completed_builds left join (select c2.*
from completed_builds as c1, completed_builds as c2
where c1.branch = c2.branch
and c1.repository = c2.repository
and c1.stop_time > c2.stop_time
) as NOT_LARGEST ON completed_builds.id = NOT_LARGEST.id
where NOT_LARGEST.id is null
```
This sql statement does the same thing. Not sure if this statement would be easier to convert to sqlalchemy?

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.

Comment: We can't write your code for you. What have you tried?

Comment: Are the multiple where statements a problem? [than you might find your answer here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_) using `sqlalchemy.and_`

Answer (score 0):

Add the filter using the subquery.

```
subq = (db.query(CompletedBuilds.id, 
                 func.max(CompletedBuilds.stop_time).label(‘max_stop_time’)
                 CompletedBuilds.branch,
                 CompletedBuilds.repository)
       .subquery())

q = (db.query(CompletedBuilds)
    .join(subq, subq.id  == CompletedBuilds.id)
    .filter( subq.branch == CompletedBuilds.branch,
            subq.repository == CompletedBuilds.repository, 
            CompletedBuilds.repository.in_(‘flex’, ‘mob’, ‘tv’), 
            CompletedBuilds.branch.in_(‘stage’, ‘int’))
    .order_by(CompletedBuilds.repository, CompletedBuilds.branch))
```